# CASE WHEN bit THEN 'something' ELSE null END shortcut

Tags: sql-server

Is there a shortcut in MS SQL Server for a call **CASE WHEN bit THEN 'something' ELSE null  END** ? Is there a way to write it differently?

**Example scenario:**

```
DECLARE @data TABLE(IsSomething BIT NOT NULL, Value NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO @data VALUES
(1, 'a'),
(1, 'b'),
(0, 'c'),
(0, 'd');

SELECT
CASE WHEN IsSomething = 1 THEN Value ELSE NULL END,
CASE WHEN IsSomething = 1 THEN 'string' ELSE NULL END,
CASE WHEN IsSomething = 0 THEN 'not ' + Value ELSE NULL END
FROM @data
```

I am especially looking for the variant where the BIT value is 1 (true).

The concern is readability of the select statement and excesively long expression to write for a simple case/if.

I use those expressions in one of my views where it bothers me the most. I am not saying the design of that view or the tables is ideal. *(In fact, it is not ideal!)*

Comment: I don't really get what you want to do

Comment: Please add your desired output

Comment: Simply a shortcut the call "CASE WHEN IsSomething = 1 THEN Value ELSE NULL END"...something like IsSomething ? Value : null or even something shorter that automatically returns null

Comment: SQL Server 2012 (and above) has the [inline if](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh213574.aspx).  Usage: *IIF(Boolean Expression, 'True Output', 'False Output')*.  @SeanLange makes a good point, if you don't constrain bits to non-null values you could trip yourself up here.

Comment: No there isn't a shortcut because a bit is NOT a Boolean. It can have 3 values, 1, 0 and NULL

Comment: Well `ELSE NULL` can be removed, its implied.  Shorter is not always better.

Comment: Even now query is readable

Comment: @AlexK. I am not saying it is, but it seems like there could be a better way to improve readability

Comment: @Santhos You think that `IsSomething ? Value : null` is more "readable" than `CASE WHEN`?

Comment: @SeanLange Note that (ANSI) SQL boolean has three values as well - True, false and unknown. Still not `bit`, though :)

Comment: @Lamak I am sorry that I touched your precious SQL CASE WHEN I AM GOING TO DIE TO WRITE THIS SIMPLE IF STATEMENT expression :) Sorry for being sarcastic...I just thought it was excesively long.

Comment: @Santhos Always a good attitude to have. Anyway, you are the one talking about readability, and I fail to see how `CASE WHEN` could be more "readable", it's literally "case when some_condition then some_value else some_other_value end"

Comment: @Lamak I see, well maybe it is just me. However, I think the important values are kind of getting lost in that.

Comment: @destination-data You should post that as an anwer. I think that is the "best" shorcut I could have at the moment. (The thing is that someone has already stolen the answer from you, but you were definitely the first to post it.)

Comment: Btw if I have to choose between omitting the **ELSE NULL** clause or **IIF(x = 1, value, null)**, I choose the later because the first does not seem to improve the readability that much - it is not that obvious it returns null. **imho**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [IIF (SQL Server 2012+)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx) which is supposed to be a shorthand for CASE, but in my opinion the query ends up being even less readable (might be a matter of habit on my end though):

```
SELECT
    IIF(IsSomething = 1, Value1, NULL) AS val1,
    IIF(IsSomething = 1, Value2, NULL) AS val2,
    IIF(IsSomething = 0, Value3, NULL) AS val3
FROM @data
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't know what you would consider a shortcut, but you could write it this way:

```
CASE IsSomething
 WHEN 1 THEN 'SomeThing'
 ELSE NULL
END
```

Comment: Without `ELSE NULL` produces the same result, i.e. `CASE IsSomething WHEN 1 THEN 'Value' END`